# Can I start and stop speech recognition with a button?

Tags: javascript, date, speech-recognition

Is there anyway to make this so that `client.on("volume-indicator")` can be stopped and started by an HTML button?

And if I want to stop the `client.on("volume-indicator")` function can I simply put it like `client.off("volume-indicator")`?

```
client.on("volume-indicator", volumes => {    
    volumes.forEach((volume) => {
        console.log(`UID ${volume.uid} Level ${volume.level}`);
        let speechRecognitionStarted = false;
        let clientspeechRecognitionStarted = false;
        let speechRecognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        let speechRecognitionStartTime = null;
        let clientspeechRecognitionStartTime = null;
        if (config.uid == volume.uid && volume.level > 50) {
            $("#user-stream").css({
                "box-shadow": "0 2px 4px 0 #0C9DFD, 0 2px 7px 0 #0C9DFD"
            });
            speechRecognition.onstart = () => {
                // Show the Status Element
                //console.log('Voice recognition activated. Try speaking into the microphone.');
                speechRecognitionStartTime = new Date();
            };
            speechRecognition.onerror = () => {
                // Hide the Status Element
                //console.log('No speech was detected. Try again.'); 
            };
            speechRecognition.onend = () => {
                if (speechRecognitionStartTime) {
                    let duration = new Date() - speechRecognitionStartTime;
                    if (speechRecognitionDurations[volume.uid]) {
                        speechRecognitionDurations[volume.uid] += duration;
                    } else {
                        speechRecognitionDurations[volume.uid] = duration;
                    }
                }
                console.log(`Duration of talk: UID ${volume.uid} ms` + speechRecognitionDurations[volume.uid]);
                if(chart) {
                    updateBarGraph();
                }
                else {
                    createBarGraph();
                    chart=true;
                }
            };
            speechRecognition.onresult = (event) => {

            }
            // start recognition
            if (!speechRecognitionStarted) {
                speechRecognition.start();
                speechRecognitionStarted = true;
                console.log(speechRecognitionStarted);
            }
        }
        else if (config.uid == volume.uid && volume.level < 50) {
            $("#video-wrapper").css({
                "box-shadow": "none"
            });
            console.log(speechRecognitionStarted);
            if(speechRecognitionStarted){
                speechRecognition.stop();
                speechRecognitionStarted = false;
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your title should be a clear, specific question and you should present your problem before throwing code at us.